# how to build dynamic query in mongodb with various conditions

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a sql query I need to make equivalent `mongodb` query I am using `c#` driver. Is it possible to create a dynamic method to create mongo equivalent of these kind of `sql` queries where I can specify dynamically what all columns should be taken with dynamically created where conditions. Please help to create mongo equivalent query using `c#`

```
SELECT distinct(employeeID), firstname, Lastname, salary, joinedOn FROM [Employees]
where salary >= 40000 and joinedOn between '2011/02/25' and '2012/02/27'
```

Comment: Whad do you mean by "using c#"? What has it to do with mongodb query language?

Comment: i'm developing my application in c# using the c# driver for mongodb

Comment: So? It doesn't matter, the query you're looking for does not depend on the platform of your app.

Comment: i'm building sql query dynamically using c#, so i would like to know is there any possibility to do the same with mongodb.

Answer (score 0):

What about use Linq to build a dynamic query?

```
  public T findOne<T> (Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression) where T: class
    {
        var db = server.GetDatabase(databaseName);
        var documents = db.GetCollection<T>(typeof(T).Name);

        return (documents.AsQueryable<T>().Where(expression)).SingleOrDefault;
    }
```

You can use it in this way:

```
var employee = findOne<Employee>(e=> d.salary>=4000 &&
                                  d.joinedOn > "2011/02/25"  &&
                                  d.joinedOn < "2012/02/27");
```

I think you should convert joinedOn to DateTime.